# Why do I get an extra white page before my TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, landscape, blank-page

I've created a little diagram in TikZ.
Only problem is, it's quite big, so I figured I should use landscape mode for it.

Only problem is, when I put it between

```
\begin{landscape}
\input{erd.tikz.tex} % my diagram
\end{landscape}
```

I get an extra white page before the diagram itself.

I can't seem to understand why, any idea?

Thanks.

Here is the document:

```
\documentclass[border=0.4in]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Foo bar bar bar foo, foo bar.
\newgeometry{left=2cm,bottom=3cm}
\begin{landscape}
\input{erd.tikz.tex}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\section{Zip}
Boom boom, zip.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use

```
\begin{landscape}
\resizebox{!}{0.95\textheight}{\input{erd.tikz.tex}}
\end{landscape}
```

The image is too big. The reason why it is placed on the following page.

Comment: Tried that.
Still no luck.

Comment: True, it should be `{0.95\textheight}`. I`ll correct it

Comment: Ah, yes luck, this time.
Wonderful.

Thanks a lot.

However, I wonder why this is needed: even without that all the *visible* picture fits neatly on the page.
Is there an invisible/fully white part of the TikZ picture?
Sounds... un-TeXish to me, for lack of a better term.

Comment: Every object (box) which cannot be placed on the current page will move to the next page.

Comment: Any hope to avoid this behavior (additional empty page) without resizing the TikZ-picture?

Comment: Yes, this puzzles me too, because, if it fits nicely in the following page, why shouldn't if fit in the first one?